# Knockout binding issue with responsive DataTables

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, responsive-design, datatables

While using *dataTables* with *Knockout*, the binding is not working when re-sizing the table.

[image]

Actually the *dataTables* removes *td* from actual *tr* and creates a new row while re-sizing the window that makes the table responsive. But the newly created rows lose it's binding. How to handle this? Whether *jQuery* event handler can be used? Please provide a clean solution for this.

Find the sample fiddle where you can click on the colors. Please re-size the output window to reproduce this problem.

---

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: fruits">
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text:$data.name"> </td> 
    <td data-bind="text:$data.color,click:$parent.displayInfo,style:{'background-color':$data.color}" class="color"> </td>   
</tr>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#myTable').DataTable({responsive:true});
```

} );

https://jsfiddle.net/Purushoth/2zrx2jf0/

Thanks!

Comment: Tried to find a solution to this myself for a little while, we ended up using No More Tables (http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table) instead. Does the same sort of thing, but without the expanding columns. If you can't find a solution, that may be an option for you (sorry this isn't the answer you're after, good luck!)